# Can I minimize the width of a paragraph, as long as its height (number of lines) remains the same?

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

Suppose I have a piece of text saying “foo bar baz qux” that doesn't fit the width of the display, so it gets broken into two lines like this:

```
foo bar baz
qux
```

Can I make it as narrow as it can be, as long as the height (number of lines) of the paragraph remain the same? I.e.,

```
foo bar
baz qux
```

Comment: Would you add a code snippet? It's easier for us that way instead of having to imagine it :)

Comment: @Helenesh it doesn't have to be a `<p>` exactly, but— https://jsfiddle.net/z71k4mts/

Comment: text-align:justify ??? This word count might get difficult.

Comment: @FarhanQasim justifying only affects the spacing between words, what I want is a different breaking strategy

Comment: we can break lines through javascript, but what if the words are not of the same length?? for example foo four foour foooour

Comment: @FarhanQasim I wouldn't want to rely on javascript; besides, as the font is proportional, the calculation could be rather heavy

Comment: There is no way to achieve this using CSS alone.